# What does at sign mean when listing directory using ls -l?

Tags: macos

I am removing the content of a directory using git reset hard, but I checked that the directories is still there and showing as

drwx------@

what does @ means here?

Comment: [duplicate](http://superuser.com/questions/155458/what-does-the-mean-on-the-output-of-ls-on-os-x-terminal)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

according to `man ls` it says:

> -@      Display extended attribute keys and sizes in long (-l) output.

and try this:

```
ls -l@
```

Comment: used, it shows  com.apple.quarantine, what does this mean?

Comment: extended attributes are used in mac os file system for various reasons. a simple explanation can also be read in here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_file_attributes. otherwise you have to go through apple docs.

Comment: and a good explanation here as well http://gotofritz.net/blog/geekery/os-x-extended-attibutes/